# Devolver número al poner nombre del mes

Tags: jquery

Tengo un campo en mi página web en la que sale el mes y el año (por ejemplo Enero 2020). Me gustaría convertir ese número en el siguiente formato: `yyyy/mm/dd`
El día es un poco más complejo, ya que hay unos cuantos condicionales. Si el mes es el actual, coger el día en el que estamos. Si no lo es, coger el primer día (también necesito coger el último día, sea el mes que sea).

De momento tengo el siguiente código:

```js
$('.fc-button-group button').click(function() {
    test = getMonth();
    // console.log(getMonthFromString(test)+ " || "+test);
});

// A partir de las siguientes dos funciones, crear el formato yyyy/mm/dd
function getMonth() {
    // string = mes + año (Enero 2020)
    var string = $(".fc-center h2").text();
    var split = string.split(" ");
    // Devuelve mes (Enero)
    return split[0];
}

function getYear() {
    // string = mes + año (Enero 2020)
    var string = $(".fc-center h2").text();
    var split = string.split(" ");
    // Devuelve año (2020)
    return split[1];
}

// Función recogida de SO en inglés, pero solo funciona con los meses en inglés.
function getMonthFromString(mon){
    var d = Date.parse(mon + "1, 2012");
    if(!isNaN(d)){
        return new Date(d).getMonth() + 1;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Se me ocurren varias maneras de hacerlo, de hecho tres maneras. No te voy a soltar el código tal cual para que investigues un poco tú. 1.- (Mi preferida), usando moment.js. 2.- usando Date(), 3.- usando un enum. Por cierto, estaría bien que dieras unos cuantos ejemplos (2) de $(".fc-center h2").text() y lo que se supone que cada función tiene que devolver

Comment: @Iria No esperaba que nadie me soltase código, sino algún consejo como el tuyo, muchas gracias! Voy a investigar un poco sobre moment.js. Ahora edito la pregunta para clarificar lo que devuelve cada función.

Comment: moment.js es una librería bastante buena, pero mucha gente no sabe como usarla y da lugar a múltiples bugs, cuidado con esto

Comment: `moment.js` sin duda es lo mejor para esto. Es una librería excelente y muy bien documentada.